# JQuery resizable splitter abnormal behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used the Jquery Resizable component, and there are three resizable divs inside a parent div. I need to make all three divs resizable appropriately, However there is an issue with the right panel and the splitter. When you try to resize it will move the other way. I've been trying to find out a solution for this but could not come up with anything.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pyq8x3f/)

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/src/jquery-resizable.js"></script>

<div class="page-container">
  <div class="panel-container">

    <div class="panel-left">
      left panel
    </div>

    <div class="splitter">
    </div>

    <div class="panel-center">
      center panel
    </div>

    <div class="splitter-right">
    </div>

    <div class="panel-right">
      right panel
    </div>


  </div>


</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(".panel-left").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".splitter",
   resizeHeight: false
 });

  $(".panel-right").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".splitter-right",
   resizeHeight: false
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working demo. I made changes to your CSS and JS. I created the splitter using JS and added the `onDragStart` function to handle it

```js
$(".panel-left,.panel-center")
     .css({
    /* required to allow resizer embedding */
    position: "relative"
  })
  /* check .resizer CSS */
  .prepend("<div class='resizer'></div>")
  .resizable({
    resizeHeight: false,
    // we use the column as handle and filter
    // by the contained .resizer element
    handleSelector: "",
    onDragStart: function(e, $el, opt) {
      // only drag resizer
      if (!$(e.target).hasClass("resizer"))
        return false;
      return true;
    }
 });
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.page-container {
  margin: 20px;
}

/* horizontal panel*/

.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* avoid browser level touch actions */
  xtouch-action: none;
}

.panel-left {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}
.resizer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: auto;
    width: 16px;
    cursor: col-resize;
    background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
}

.panel-center {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

.panel-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/src/jquery-resizable.js"></script>

<div class="page-container">
  <div class="panel-container">

    <div class="panel-left">
      left panel
    </div>

    <div class="panel-center">
      center panel
    </div>
    
    <div class="panel-right">
      right panel
    </div>


  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: This is great, But I can't fully move the right splitter to the way right. And It also snaps to the left whenever trying to move

Comment: @GaniduRanasinghe I guess you cant. because by default the right panel will have width, ref : http://prntscr.com/kf6pu8 , so that it will move to `0` from that point to the max